# Lancia Kappa SW Turbo Dual Mass Flywheel

Tags: clutch

Is there any proper source where I could find a list of cars with Dual Mass Flywheels (DMF)?

I have an opportunity to buy the said car, but I had some bad experience with DMF, so I would avoid them at all costs.

(Also, does anyone know if the 162kw petrol Lancia Kappa has one?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had never heard of a DMF car before, so did some reading. Those things look like a mechanical nightmare (a breakdown waiting to happen). No clue how they are supposed to give you better fuel mileage (as advertised), considering there is movement between the two masses. Here in the US I don't believe *any* car uses a DMF and don't know why they would.  Regular flywheels have been working just fine without producing vibrations for a long, long time. You just have to use them right ...

Comment: @Paulster2 - DMFs have been commonly fitted to diesel vehicles in Europe for the last 10 years or so, and are a right pain - they usually need changing at the same time as the clutch, and cost a fortune to do... I'm not aware of many petrol cars with them though

Comment: @NickC I first seen it on diesel ones, and talked to a friend of mine who is a mechanic, and says that a lot of (EU) petrol cars above 2.0 L engine usually have one, if they are fitted with a manual transmission. Unfortunately I found it very hard to determine which car needs this part, as most of the sites are built that they advertise Universal DMFs, and even state that it fits cars that I know don't have this part.

Comment: @Alex Indeed, googling for parts is often useless like that, they'll advertise a part with keywords for hundreds of different models/variants just to try to get you to their site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know DMF is expensive, but if you really like a car and don't wonna have a DMF, you can change it to regular fix flywheel. Valeo producing such a kits. So just check, if there exist such a kit for your car. I don't think there is a list of DMF cars, but you can ask you part shop which one is in for the car you like.

Comment: Thanks, but won't the converted kit mean shorter lifetime for the clutch, etc?

Comment: Few years ago I used such a kit. The car drove about 100tkm and the clutch was still ok. It was a Ford Mondeo. I think its only bad for the clutch if you drive with very low RPM (vibration much higher).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've never heard anyone who actually had his DMF replaced, and the low RPM vibration parts seems logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look on the www.luk.co.uk for all the information you want. Dual Mass Flywheels are usually fitted to diesel vehicles. They reduce torsional vibrations through the transmission, promoting longer gearbox life. The lack of vibrations contribute to greater driver comfort and so less stress. They also play a part in improved emissions contol. People who decry the DMF usually do so the basis of cost and do not really appreciate the advance in the technology of todays transmissions. When you think about it, the traditional clutch driven plate with its torsional springs is a fore-runner of the DMF.